# Project structure doesn't update after changing branch

Tags: android, git, android-studio, atlassian-sourcetree

this issues seems trivial to me and I'm sure that lots of developers encountered it but somehow I couldn't find the answer to it.

I'm working on git repository with 2 branches - master and dev. After doing some work on master, including creating new files and packages, stashing all the changes and then checkout 'dev' branch - all of the new files and packages I stashed before are still visible on Android studio and so interrupting the compilation process.

I'm using SourceTree for all the git operations.

Comment: try git remote update command.

Comment: nope. Unfortunately it didn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, 'git stash' doesn't include untracked files so you have to use the '-u' option. Otherwise, they staying the working directory when you check out the other branch.

Comment: I'm not religious but - god bless you